# Golang: Explain DumpRequest and DumpResponse HTTP/2

Tags: go, http2, glide-golang

```
clientt := &http.Client{
    Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
}
var tr = &http2.Transport{}
clientt.Transport = tr
```

I create a client and send http/2 request. with http2 transport
but in DumpRequest I see
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [www.xxxxq23.com](http://www.xxxxq23.com)

In response dump I see HTTP/2.0

Why request use HTTP/1.1 ?
How to change to HTTP/2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/2 is binary, instead of textual and dumping in binary would be unreadable and useless. It is intentional by design and it is well [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/):

> DumpRequest returns the given request in its HTTP/1.x wire
> representation. It should only be used by servers to debug client
> requests. The returned representation is an approximation only; some
> details of the initial request are lost while parsing it into an
> http.Request. In particular, the order and case of header field names
> are lost. The order of values in multi-valued headers is kept intact.
> HTTP/2 requests are dumped in HTTP/1.x form, not in their original
> binary representations.
>
> If body is true, DumpRequest also returns the body. To do so, it
> consumes req.Body and then replaces it with a new io.ReadCloser that
> yields the same bytes. If DumpRequest returns an error, the state of
> req is undefined.

You can checkout the implementation details [here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/http2)